# Website loading slowly - Advanced Custom Fields images

Tags: custom-taxonomy, images, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently using `get_field` with Advanced  Custom Fields plugin ([see here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/)) to get a single image for search results. The end result is that these pages are loading slow, as I believe this is due to MySQL returning the whole array of all images in the gallery for the specified page, which ends up being huge.

To load the image, I am currently doing the following:

```
$image = get_field('house_photos'); 

    if ($image) {

        echo '<img src="' . $image[0]['sizes']['house_search'] . '"  />'; 

    }
```

Is there a more efficient way just to get this single image without requesting the entire array?

Comment: I don't have any test-cases of my own, but you are returning the image object compared to just returning the ID and then running it through WP functions like `wp_get_attachment_image_src`, so it may be something to consider (the image object is doing/returning more than you may need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to work it out - the function was leading to a lot of queries, so I rewrote it as follows:

```
    $housePhotos = get_post_custom_values('house_photos');

    $housePhotos = explode(';',$housePhotos[0]);

    preg_match_all('`"([^"]*)"`', $housePhotos[1], $results);

    $imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $results[1][0], 'house_search' );

    if (!empty($results[1][0])) {

        echo '<img src="' . $imageURL[0] .'" alt="" />'; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In advanced custom value if you adding field choose field type "image"  & choose return value "Image URL".
To display image use

```
$image = get_field('house_photos'); 
    if ($image) {
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '"  />'; 
    }
```

If you return the ID, you'd use:

```
$image_id = get_field('house_photos');
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full');

if ($image_id) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image_src[0].'" width="'.$image_src[1].'" height="'.$image_src[2].'">';
}
```

Comment: The problem is with `get_field()` itself, when retrieving a gallery field. Having the same issue. Ollie's answer seems promising though.

Answer (score 0):

You coudld just use `$housePhotos = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'house_photos', true )` to get an array of the image id's. Then you could get the first image by saying `$imageURL = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $housePhotos[0], 'house_search' );`